# Sort a typed array of object with a lambda expression

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda

I run into a problem that I do not understand.
In the method of adding in the Table class I would like to use:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(asso, (a,b) -> a.cle.compareTo(b.cle));
```

Where asso is my array of Association objects containing the key and the value.

By executing this code with the type String, I get an error "cannot find symbol"  on the method compareTo(Object).

There my code:

test:

```
Table<String,String> table0 = new Table<String,String>(10);
table0.add("1","int");
```

method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Table<C,V>{

  Association[] asso;

  public Table(int n){
    asso = new Association[n];
  }

  public void add(C cle, V valeur){
    asso[0] = new Association<C,V>(cle,valeur);
    Arrays.sort(asso, (a,b) -> a.cle.compareTo(b.cle));
  }

  public class Association<C,V>{

    public C cle;
    public V valeur;

    public Association(C cle,V valeur){
      this.cle = cle;
      this.valeur = valeur;
    }
  }
}
```

And the error:

```
../src/Table.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
Arrays.sort(asso, (a,b) -> a.cle.compareTo(b.cle));
                                ^
symbol:   method compareTo(Object)
location: variable cle of type C
where C is a type-variable:
C extends Object declared in class Table.Association
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a type bound to the generic type parameter `C`:

```
class Table<C extends Comparable<C>,V>
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know that `C` implements `Comparable` (and therefore must have the `compareTo` method).

Also don't use raw type (`Association[]`) for the array. Use:

```
Association<C,V>[] asso;
```

On second thought, I also suggest you make the `Association` class `static`:

```
public class Table<C extends Comparable<C>,V> {

    Association<C,V>[] asso;

    public Table(int n) {
        asso = new Association[n];
    }

    public void add(C cle, V valeur) {
        asso[0] = new Association<C,V>(cle,valeur);
        Arrays.sort(asso, (a,b) -> a.cle.compareTo(b.cle));
    }

    public static class Association<C,V> {

        public C cle;
        public V valeur;

        public Association(C cle,V valeur){
            this.cle = cle;
            this.valeur = valeur;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have done 
`class Association<C extends Comparable<C>,V>`
`class Table<C extends Comparable<C>,V>`

and now i have the error:

    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Table.lambda$ajout$0(Table.java:15)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
 at Table.ajout(Table.java:15)
 at main.main(main.java:546)`

Comment: @takesuma The NullPointerException is a separate issue. You are trying to sort an array that has 1 `Association` instance and 9 null references. Besides, your `add` method always assigns to the first index of the array, which can't be right.

Comment: @takesuma yes, unless you change your lambda expression to handle the case where `a` or `b` are null.

Comment: I tried this:  
`Arrays.sort(asso, (@NotNull C a,@NotNull C b) -> a.cle.compareTo(b.cle));`
  but it don't work
it's my first use of lambda so i don't know well how it works.

Comment: @takesuma what do you expect `@NotNull` to do?

Comment: @takesuma just use `Arrays.sort(asso, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing (Association::getCle)));` (and add a getter method `getCle()` to Association class).

Comment: the @NotNull is a thing that i see on the web but after quick research i found it nowhere else.

Comment: i tried something like that:
Arrays.binarySearch(asso, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing (Association::getCle)))

Comment: i want to search in asso by cle